# Using Group by in Linq to get array or Ienumerable of datatable

Tags: c#, linq

What I have is table like this:

```
Col1          Col2        Col3
1              A            ABCD
2              B            EFGH
3              A            MNOP
4              B            PQRS
```

I want linq query which will give Ienumerable as return of data tables where column values are same.

```
1           A       ABCD
3           A       MNOP

2           B       EFGH
4           B       PQRS
```

What I tried is:

```
(From p In d1.AsEnumerable() Group By x= New With { Key.a =p.Item("Col2")} Into Group Select Group(0)).ToArray().CopyToDataTable()
```

But how do I select entire array of datatable (group) not just group(0) or group(1)?

Comment: Use OrderBy instead of GroupBy.  The Group gives a two dimensional array while the OrderBy gives a one dimensional array.  If you use the GroupBy then you would have to use a SelectMany which will take the two dimensional array and make it one dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You could do the following

```
var result = d1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x=>x["Col2"]).Select(x=>x.CopyToDataTable());
```

In the solution, you are grouping by Column `Col2` and using `CopyToDataTable` to create tables.

Output Sample

[image]

Comment: I am workin on uipath so lamda expresison dont work here yet

Comment: Hello Guys (From p In d1.AsEnumerable() Group By x= New With { Key.a =p.Item("Col4")} Into Group Select Group.copytodatatable()) WOKRED THE DROP DOWN FOR COPYTODATATABLE DIDNT SHOW AND HENCE I GOT CONFUSED WHETHER IT WAS POSSIBLE

Comment: @ankitkwar glad to help u. Kindly mark it answer if it helped you resolve the issue